# How to correctly remove an event listener for each element in a foreach?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know very little javascript, and after a fair amount of sweating and cutting together pieces from around the web, I came to the piece of code pasted below. I'm aware it's surely far from elegant or streamline, but as said, I barely put it together... if someone would want to help me streamline it, that would be appreciated, but my main concer is another.

What the code does is take all html elements in the page with a data-value attribute (e.g. div data-value="50"), check if they're appearing on screen (using the scroll event listener), and run an animation counter inside them from 0 to the number of the data-value attribute.
It's all working, up to this point.

Problem is I need to remove the event listener for each specific html element after that element has come into view (basically: when item comes into view once, run the animation and forget about it), but all I've tried didn't work.
If I don't remove the listener, every single small scroll makes the counters start again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  /* ----- Number Counter Animation ----- */
  function animateValue(obj, start, end, duration) {
    let startTimestamp = null;
    const step = (timestamp) => {
      if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
      const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
      obj.innerHTML = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
      if (progress < 1) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }

  var isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  };

  const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-value]");

  function checkVis(item) {
    item.forEach(el=>{
      if (isInViewport(el)) {
        var val = el.getAttribute("data-value");
        animateValue(el, 0, val, 3000);
      }
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    checkVis(elements);
  }, false);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
here is a working solution.
first i add another data attribute named "data-animated" with a start value "false" to the elements i want to animate.

```
<div class="num" data-animated="false" data-value="50"> 0 </div>
<div class="num" data-animated="false" data-value="85"> 0 </div>
```

then i am changing the "data-animated" value to "true" after the animation is performed (see comment).

and befor calling the "animateValue" function i added a condition which checks the "data-animated" value and alows the calling only if it's "false" (see comment).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

/* ----- Number Counter Animation ----- */
function animateValue(obj, start, end, duration) {
    let startTimestamp = null;
    const step = (timestamp) => {
      if (!startTimestamp) startTimestamp = timestamp;
      const progress = Math.min((timestamp - startTimestamp) / duration, 1);
      obj.innerHTML = Math.floor(progress * (end - start) + start);
      if (progress < 1) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
      }
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    obj.setAttribute("data-animated", "true"); // set attribute value to "true"
  }

  var isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      bounding.top >= 0 &&
      bounding.left >= 0 &&
      bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  };

  const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-value]");

  function checkVis(item) {
    item.forEach(el => {
      if (isInViewport(el)) {
    var val = el.getAttribute("data-value");
    if (el.getAttribute("data-animated") === "false") { // check's if "data-animated" is "false"
          animateValue(el, 0, val, 3000);
        }
      }
    });
  }
      window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    checkVis(elements);
  }, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to work. Actually, it prevents the animations from running entirely, it seems. I sroll down to the elements, and the animations just don't start.

Comment: @Erdren ok. here is another aproach:
after runing the animation, change the element's "data-value's" value to 'false', and call the "animateValue" only if the element's data-value isn't 'false'.

Comment: I probably didn't use that correclty due to my almost null knowledge of javascript, but what I've tried either didn't make the counters start or made "NaN" appear in place of the numbers (in which case I suppose the data-value is set to false at the very first scroll and thus is not a number).

Comment: you have to change the element's "data-value' after the animation was performed and only for the specific element. if you will add the full code maybe i will be more helpful.

Comment: Full code is already in the opening post, except this bit you suggested about changing data-value because I don't know where exactly I should add it.

If you meant to ask for the html, it's simply:

`code`
<div class="num" data-value="50">
0
</div>
<div class="num" data-value="85">
0
</div>
`code`

There are more divs, but only the data-value changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding another attribute didn't come to mind at all... I had tried something similar with variables all inside the code, to no avail, but this now works exactly as intended.
Really thanks.

Comment: you are welcome. I will appreciate if you will up-vote my answer. Thanks.